# Git Post-Push hook replacing build folder

Tags: php, git, azure, webhooks, continuous-deployment

I'm working with an AngularJS app that I am hosting on Azure as a Web App.

My repository is on [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/), connected as a deployment slot. I use [TortoiseGit](https://tortoisegit.org/) as a Windows shell for `commit/pull/push`. [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) is my task runner.

---

**Problem**: I am not managing to replace the `build` folder after a push has been made. This is what is being exposed on Azure (*see picture*):

[image]

---

**What I've tried**:

- Batch file using Windows ftp.exe replacing the folder after push using `mput`
- Following this [guide](http://www.cptloadtest.com/2013/12/03/Git-And-Grunt-Deploy-To-Windows-Azure.aspx) by taking advantages of [Azure's engine for git deployment(s)](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu) that is behind every web app.
- [WebHook on Bitbucket](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/manage-webhooks-735643732.html) calling URL with simple PHP script doing a FTP upload

---

Currently my solution is that after a push I'm building using `grunt build` and connecting through FTP with FileZilla and replacing `build` folder manually.

How can I automate this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by refactor my initial batch script that calls:

```
npm install 
bower install 
grunt clean 
grunt build
winscp.com /script=azureBuildScript.txt
```

and my azureBuildScript.txt:

```
option batch abort
option confirm off
open ftps://xxx\xxx:xxx@waws-prod-db3-023.ftp.azurewebsites.windows.net/
cd site/wwwroot
rmdir %existingFolder%
put %myFolder%
exit
```

This is being triggered Post-Push as a Hook job in TortoiseGit.

It turns out `ftp.exe` is restricted regarding passive mode and can't interpret a session whilst [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/index.php)  does this with ease.